# Can I turn PC into a server?Does it have to stay online all the time?

Tags: server, client-server

Is it possible?

I know the answer may depend on what kind of work the server will be doing - game server, host server, mail server etc.

Does it always have to stay online, because it is by definition has become a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, it's not that hard and as far as i know it has to be online all the time!

[Follow this article](http://www.liutilities.com/how-to/turn-your-computer-into-a-server/)